# How can determine managed identity of Azure VM a script is running on?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-vm

For post-processing of `AzD=Azure Developer CLI` I need to authorize the managed identity of the Azure VM, the script is currently running on, to the subscription selected by `AzD`. How can I determine managed identity of the VM with help of the metadata endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I created this script `authorize-vm-identity.sh` which determines the VM's resourceID (could be in a different subscription than the actual resources managed by `AzD`) from the metadata endpoint and then obtains the managed identities' `principalId` to make the actual role assignment with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source <(azd env get-values | sed 's/AZURE_/export AZURE_/g')
AZURE_VM_ID=`curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01" | jq -r '.compute.resourceId'`

if [ ! -z $AZURE_VM_ID ];
then
    AZURE_VM_MI_ID=`az vm show --id $AZURE_VM_ID --query 'identity.principalId' -o tsv`
fi

if [ ! -z $AZURE_VM_MI_ID ];
then
    az role assignment create --role Contributor --assignee $AZURE_VM_MI_ID --scope /subscriptions/$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
fi
```

*Prerequisites:*

- Azure CLI
- jq
- curl